# Using multiple HashMaps to retrieve values in Java

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Consider two `HashMap`s. The first one contains the product name and product category code as key and value respectively.  The second `HashMap` contains the product name and the units sold. I need to write a  Java function which accepts the two hash maps and return the names of products in each category which is having the highest number of units sold.

```
Input1 :{“lux”:”soap”,”colgate”:”paste”, ”pears”:”soap”,”sony”:”electronics”,”samsung”:”electronics”}
Input 2:{“lux”:1000,”colgate”:500,”pears”:2000,”sony”:100,” samsung”,600}
Output: {“pears”,”colgate”,”samsung”}
```

Comment: Im trying to create a java program which has two hashmaps. for example if there are two products of same category, (Product A and B in the category Soap), i should find the product havin max price in a particular category and should find the product having max price in each category

Comment: better to provide the your code rather than explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Arjun: answer code is given below :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class MultipleHashMapAccessDemo {

    protected Map<String, String> getProductCategoryMap() {
        Map<String, String> productCategoryMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        productCategoryMap.put("Lux", "Soap");
        productCategoryMap.put("Pears", "Soap");
        productCategoryMap.put("Dove", "Soap");
        productCategoryMap.put("Colgate", "Paste");
        productCategoryMap.put("Babul", "Paste");
        productCategoryMap.put("Vico", "Paste");

        return productCategoryMap;
    }

    protected Map<String, Integer> getProductUnitsSoldMap() {
        Map<String, Integer> productUnitsSoldMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        productUnitsSoldMap.put("Lux", 1000);
        productUnitsSoldMap.put("Pears", 3000);
        productUnitsSoldMap.put("Dove", 3010);
        productUnitsSoldMap.put("Colgate", 50);
        productUnitsSoldMap.put("Babul", 45);
        productUnitsSoldMap.put("Vico", 80);

        return productUnitsSoldMap;
    }

    protected Map<String, String> getExpectedProductCategoryMap(
            Map<String, String> productCategoryMap,
            Map<String, Integer> productUnitsSoldMap) {

        Map<String, String> expectedProductCategoryMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Set<String> categortSet = new HashSet<String>();

        Iterator iterator = productCategoryMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> mEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
            categortSet.add(mEntry.getValue());
        }

        for (String category : categortSet) {
            int tempUnits = 0;
            String desiredProductName = null;

            for (Object object : productUnitsSoldMap.entrySet()) {
                Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = (Map.Entry<String, Integer>) object;

                String product = entry.getKey();
                if (category.equals(productCategoryMap.get(product))) {
                    if (tempUnits < entry.getValue()) {
                        tempUnits = entry.getValue();
                        desiredProductName = product;
                    }
                }
            }
            expectedProductCategoryMap.put(category, desiredProductName);
        }
        return expectedProductCategoryMap;
    }

    public static void main(String... strings) {

        MultipleHashMapAccessDemo accessDemo = new MultipleHashMapAccessDemo();
        Map<String, String> productCategoryMap = accessDemo
                .getProductCategoryMap();
        Map<String, Integer> productUnitsSoldMap = accessDemo
                .getProductUnitsSoldMap();

        Map<String, String> expectedProductCategoryMap = accessDemo
                .getExpectedProductCategoryMap(productCategoryMap,
                        productUnitsSoldMap);

        for (Object object : expectedProductCategoryMap.entrySet()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> entry = (Map.Entry<String, String>) object;

            System.out.print("Category name is : " + entry.getValue());
            System.out.println(" And Product name is : " + entry.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I'll hold a map with from the category to the most popular item and its counter. You can either do this with two separate `Map`s, jimmy up a quick and dirty class to hold the info, or use something like [Apache Commons Lang's Pair class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html). Without relying on any third party, I'd just define a simple class like this:

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    int amount;

    // constructor from name, amount

    // getters and setters
}
```

Now, you can iterate over the sales map and just save the most popular item for each category:

```
public Set<String> getPopularItems
    (Map<String, String> itemCategories, 
     Map<String, Integer> itemSales) {

    Map<String, Item> result = new HashMap<String, Item();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> salesEntry: itemSales) {
        String itemName = itemSales.getKey();
        int itemAmount = itemSales.getValue();

        String category = itemCategories.get(itemName);

        if (result.contiansKey(category)) {
            int currAmount = result.get(category).getAmount();
            if (itemAmount > currAmount) {
                result.put (category, new Item (itemName, itemAmount));
            }
        } else {
            result.put (category, new Item (itemName, itemAmount));
        }
    }

    return result.keySet();
}
```

Note that this is a simplified implementation that does not deal with malformed inputs (e.g., a category that appears in one map but not the other), or with edge cases (e.g., two items with the same amount of sales). This is done for clarity's sake - I'm sure you could add these on later if needed.